# Can the Community user comment suggesting adding code/documentation be updated to fit SFF?

Tags: feature-request, comments, community

An answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211741/how-did-shaddam-corrino-iv-die) contains the following  comment by the automated [Community](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) "user":

> Please add further details to expand on your answer, **such as working code or documentation citations**.

This  comes across as quite tone-deaf about the types of posts the SFF site gets. (I guess this was a stock comment, inherited from Stack Overflow, added by some sort of automated review bot).

Is it possible to customize this comment to something more appropriate to SFF?

A good working start would be

> Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as citations and quotations from relevant/reputable sources.

Comment: I would hope that anyone who answers this question will provide working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Valorum In this case, it might even be appropriate :p.

Comment: This is part of the new review queue changes, of which there are many problems (though the comments attributed to Community would be a good thing if only they were better written for each site). [This particular complaint has already been made on the main meta thread for the new review queues.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369111/299342)

Comment: The worst part is that these comments can't be deleted even by diamond moderators. Apparently we can edit them, though I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Can they get automatically deleted with enough "No longer needed" flags? Though that doesn't help much.

Comment: @Clockwork Feel free to try it, but I think flagging fails with the same error message as mod-deleting. I did edit one of those inappropriate Community comments to something useful today, so can confirm that editing works.

Comment: Seems like [SE staff have heard our complaints and the issues are planned to be solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yup, I just tried flagging and it says "This comment will be automatically removed by the system when the post is corrected"

Answer (score 6):

The standard comment [has been updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/369111/8) and is now more generic:

> As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

or

> Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.